# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in app.js in laravel

Tags: java, jquery, node.js, laravel

I'm trying to work with javascript in app.js in laravel using this package and this is my code,

```
import "../../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js";
import "../../../node_modules/parallax-imagescroll/jquery.imageScroll.js";

require('jquery');

$.fn.imageScroll.defaults.coverRatio = 0.5;
$('.img-holder').imageScroll();

/* --------------------------------------------------------------- */
$(function () {
    $('#scroll').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
            },
            500,
            'linear'
        );
    });
});
```

but when I run it using chrome and see the dev tool,

I got this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:89)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (app.js:70)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at app.js:63
    at app.js:66
```

I have no idea about this. I am doing it right?

Comment: Why are you including jQuery twice? Once using `import` and once using `require`.

Comment: just experimenting.. if it would work..